# Implementing offsetof() for structures in Python ctypes

Tags: python, c, padding, ctypes, ffi

I cannot seem to implement offsetof for a structure in ctypes.  I have seen the
[FAQ for ctypes](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ctypes), but either it doesn't work, or
I cannot figure out the details.

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec 19 2010, 13:04:47) [C] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class Dog(Structure):
...   _fields_ = [('name', c_char_p), ('weight', c_int)]
...   def offsetof(self, field):
...     return addressof(field) - addressof(self)
... 
>>> d = Dog('max', 80)
>>> d.offsetof(d.weight)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in offsetof
TypeError: invalid type
>>> d.offsetof(weight)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'weight' is not defined
>>> d.offsetof('weight')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in offsetof
TypeError: invalid type
```

It seems `addressof()` does not work on structure members (e.g. `d.weight`).  I have tried
other things involving `pointer()` and `byref()`, but no luck.

Of course I want this to work on all architectures, regardless of the size of a pointer,
and regardless of the effects of padding, so please don't say to just sum the sizeof()
for all previous elements, unless you can ensure that you're taking any padding the C
compiler adds into account.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
class Dog(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('name', c_char_p), ('weight', c_int)]

Dog.name.offset
# 0
Dog.weight.offset
# 4 (on my 32-bit system)
```

The task of turning this into a method is left to the reader :)

Comment: Thank you!  Good grief, that was easy.  I can't find it in the doc for ctypes, but I will re-read it.

Comment: The docs of ctypes are somewhat incomplete -- maybe it's missing.

Comment: @zhangyoufu: It's neither clear what you mean by "doesn't work", nor by "for array".  Do you mean that this won't yield the right offsets for structures containing arrays?  Works for me: http://ideone.com/IT8iee

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I'm sorry. There's a mistake in my code. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that structure members are sometimes returned as plain python types.
For example

```
class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('f1', c_char), ('f2', c_char * 0)]
```

type(Test().f1) is type(Test().f2) is str

Comment: Not an issue if you use the class itself, not an instance - as in the accepted answer: Test.f1, Test.f2 gives <Field type=c_char, ofs=0, size=1>, <Field type=c_char_Array_0, ofs=1, size=0>. (That is, c_char and c_char_Array.)

Comment: @Andris: The only way to recover the types from that is by parsing `repr(Test.f1)` though, which is super ugly

Comment: It looks like `gc.get_referents(Test.f1)[0]` does the job, but it's only marginally less ugly...